# how to return custom data with response in Customer API

Tags: magento2, module, api

I am calling Magento2 API **/V1/customers/me** I want to add custom data in response of this API that is stored in my custom table how can I implement this ?

Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

You should add this custom data via extension attributes. The approach for this is well documented, links below:

- https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/php/development/components/add-attributes/

You'll want to set these extension attributes on `\Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface` for your use case.

Answer (score -1):

To implement custom data in response, you need to create a custom API, i.e., with a custom module first, so you code your custom API.

You need to extend the functionality of your model like Vendor -> Module -> Model. And add your code in the **getData()** function call the other module dependencies if you want.

Just like this:

```
class GetCustomer implements GetCustomerInterface
{

 /**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */

public function getData()
{  
     
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); // Instance of object manager
    $resource = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');
    $connection = $resource->getConnection();

    $tableName = $resource->getTableName('your_table_name');

    $select = $connection->select()
    ->from(
   ['p' => $tableName]);

   $data = $connection->fetchAll($select);

   return $data;

}

}
```

If you didn't understand anything or need further justification, feel free to ask.

Comment: @Syed Hassan Zamir Do let me know if you don't know anything about how to create a module and just extend your module for a custom response instead of down vote the answer.